# how to save the selected data in csv file by using perl

Tags: oracle, perl, csv

Mine Perl Script

```
my$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT city,state address FROM address ");
$sth->execute;
    DBI::dump_results($sth);
```

The above script works fine and it showing output well as bellow

```
'aaa', 'aa'
'aaa', 'aa'
'city', 'KA'
'city', 'KA'
'city', 'KA'
```

My question is the resultent output is should be saved in `.csv` file in my local machine . Is it possible achieve as my requirement, Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { eol => "\n" } );
my $sql = "SELECT city,state address FROM address";

my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sql);


open $fh, ">", "new.csv" or die "new.csv: $!";
for my $row (@$rows) {
  $csv->print ($fh, $row);
}
close $fh or die "new.csv: $!";
```

Comment: showing error `GLOB(0x11205c8)
GLOB(0x11205c8)
GLOB(0x11205c8)
` like

Comment: @Ram My bad, remove `print $fh "\n";` line; then look at `new.csv`

Comment: works gud but it also showing some error like `GLOB(0x10bc2c8)
`

Comment: @Ram Did you remove `print $fh "\n";`

Comment: How many rows I'm selecting by using query that many errors showing with GLOB(0x10bc2c8)

Comment: @Ram `GLOB(0x10bc2c8)` is not error, it just print $fh object. However if you remove that line in the above comment, you should never see that again.

Comment: your answer works perfectly thank you for resolving requirement

Comment: `for $row` iterates just once.

Comment: Here what is the functionality of `@$rows`??

Comment: From DBI doc: **[`selectall_arrayref`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm#selectall_arrayref) returns a reference to an array containing a reference to an array for each row of data fetched.** so if your query returns 10 rows, `$rows` array has 10 reference to an array, each of which contains the actual data.

Comment: Thank you .. `{ eol => "\n" }` what about this??

Comment: Try something else rather than `"\n"` to see the differences.

Comment: I mean here what is meant by `eol` .I tried already with out this but showing only one row

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48761/discussion-between-vanda-and-ram)

Answer (score 1):

Fetch from the $sth and use [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) or [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV) to produce CSV data:

```
my $select = $db->prepare('select city, state address from address');
$select->execute;

my $c = 'Text::CSV'->new({ eol => "\n" });
open my $OUT, '>', 'new.csv' or die $!;
while (my $row = $select->fetchrow_arrayref) {
    $c->print($OUT, $row);
}
close $OUT or die $!;
```

Comment: works gud but it also showing some error like GLOB(0x10bc2c8)

Comment: How many rows I'm selecting by using query that many errors showing with `GLOB(0x10bc2c8) `

Comment: Do you use `print` instead of `$c->print`?

Comment: If i use `print` instead of `$c->print` it showing one more error like `ARRAY(0xff9698)GLOB(0x11fd8e8)`

Comment: `$c->print` works for me. Did you add any other prints?

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need, tested code.

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { eol => "\n" } );

open my $fh, ">", "data.csv" or die $!;

foreach my $row ( @{ $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT city,state address FROM address") } ) {
    $csv->print( $fh, $row );
}

close $fh;
```